# Get Spain time in C#

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-functions

I need to get Spanish time in an Azure Function. I have used this code in C#:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.UtcNow;
```

It give me an incorrect datetime and I don't know how I can the correct datetime.

For example, if I use the code above at 20:30 in Spanish time, I will get 18:30 in utc.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `DateTimeOffset` type instead of `DateTime`

```
 // First get the TimeZone by ID. Spain Timezone is "Romance Standard Time"
 var tz = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Romance Standard Time");
 // This would return +1 in winter and +2 in summer when daylight saving is active
 var offset = tz.GetUtcOffset(DateTime.UtcNow);
 // Get Time based on the current offset (+1 in winter +2 in summer)
 var now = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToOffset(offset);
```

Update for Azure since apparently TimezoneInfo is not present in the machine registry

```
// Timezones are usually stored in windows registry. Since apparently it is not stored on Azure, we can recreate the TimeZoneInfo object manually
// This is the Spanish Timezone based on current Ppanish law.
var tz = TimeZoneInfo.CreateCustomTimeZone(
    id: "Romance Standard Time", 
    baseUtcOffset: TimeSpan.FromHours(1), 
    displayName: "(UTC+01:00) Brussels, Copenhagen, Madrid, Paris", 
    standardDisplayName: "Romance Standard Time", 
    daylightDisplayName: "Romance Daylight Time",
    adjustmentRules: new[] {
        TimeZoneInfo.AdjustmentRule.CreateAdjustmentRule(
            dateStart: DateTime.MinValue,
            dateEnd: DateTime.MaxValue,
            daylightDelta: TimeSpan.FromHours(1),
            daylightTransitionStart: TimeZoneInfo.TransitionTime.CreateFloatingDateRule(
                timeOfDay: new DateTime(1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Unspecified), // Starts at 2AM
                month: 3, // Daylight starts on March 
                week: 5, // Last week of the month
                dayOfWeek: DayOfWeek.Sunday), // Starts on Sunday
            daylightTransitionEnd: TimeZoneInfo.TransitionTime.CreateFloatingDateRule(
                timeOfDay: new DateTime(1, 1, 1, 3, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Unspecified),  // Ends at 3AM
                month: 10, // Daylight ends in October
                week: 5, // Last week of October
                dayOfWeek: DayOfWeek.Sunday) // Ends On Sunday
            )
    });

// This would return +1 in winter and +2 in summer when daylight saving is active
var offset = tz.GetUtcOffset(DateTime.UtcNow);
// Get Time based on the current offset (+1 in winter +2 in summer)
var now = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToOffset(offset);
```

An important note though, .NET class library takes in consideration only the current laws regarding daylight saving and timezone. If you want to take into consideration historical changes use [Noda Time Library](https://nodatime.org/)

Comment: It doesn't work on Azure. Error: **The time zone ID 'Romance Standard Time' was not found on the local computer.**

Comment: I updated my answer for a way you can create `TimeZoneInfo` object manually. But you will have to change it everytime Spanish goverment changes the laws about Daylight time. Otherwise you can use NodaTime.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to convert the UTC time running in Azure Functions into the time zone you require, similar to this:

```
TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(
    DateTime.UtcNow,
    TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Romance Standard Time");
```

Comment: Same error that I've written  in answer by Sherif. Error: **The time zone ID 'Romance Standard Time' was not found on the local computer.**

Comment: I guess you'll need to investigate using NodaTime then.

Answer (score -1):

UTC is Universal Time
you can use

```
DateTime.Now()
```

for show local time

Comment: The local time won't be usable in an Azure Function.